# How can i stub existing function using sinon and mocha?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have a file named **index.js**

```
const addNumber = (num1, num2) => {
    console.log('function called');
    return num1 + num2;
}

const main = () => {
    const result = addNumber(2,5);
    console.log({ result });
    return result;
}

module.exports = { 
    main,
}
```

I want to write unit test case, where i can actually stub the **main** method using sinon.
For this i created a testfile named **test.js**.

```
const { it, describe } = require('mocha');
const sinon = require('sinon');

// Import the main function 
const { main } = require('./index');
const stubObj = {
    main,
}

describe('It should mock the function', () => {
    it('It should test successfully', () =>{
       const stubMain = sinon.stub(stubObj, "main");
       const beforeStubbingFunction = main();

       stubMain.returns(100)

       const afterStubbingFunction = main();

       console.log({ beforeStubbingFunction, afterStubbingFunction });

    })
  
})
```

Inside package.json file

```
{
  "name": "sinonmock",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "sinon": "^14.0.1"
  }
}
```

I used **npm run start** to run test case.
Output:

```
  It should mock the function
function called
{ result: 7 }
function called
{ result: 7 }
{ beforeStubbingFunction: 7, afterStubbingFunction: 7 }
    ✔ It should test successfully
```

**Problem**
The problem is even after stubbing the function **main**, actual main function is called.
I have stubbed main function to return 100, but it return 7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i got the solution.

Change the content of **index.js**

```
const { it, describe } = require('mocha');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const production = require('./index');

describe('Sinon tets', () => {
    it('It should mock the function value', () => {
        const beforeMocking = production.main();
        console.log({ beforeMocking, production });

        const mock = sinon.stub(production, "main");
        mock.returns(1000);

        const afterMocking = production.main();
        console.log({ afterMocking });
    })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.